# Engineering Economics Cash Flow Diagram

Tags: finance, economics

I have the following question and solution below. What I don't understand is why is the 100,000 seen as savings/revenue when clearly it is coming out of pocket? Additionally, the monthly loan payment was calculated to be 3,108/month. Since we are including this in the cash flow diagram along with the 240,000 (plus 100,000 cash payment) purchase, isn't that counting the purchase twice?

**Question:**
Your company is considering the purchase of new earth moving equipment. The total purchase is \$240,000 and we pay with \$100,000 cash and borrow the rest. (12% per year nominal, compounded monthly for 5 years). The machines last for 7 years and will be worth \$35,000 at the end of 7 years. The machines will save approximately \$20 per ton of dirt moved. Operating costs for the equipment are \$500 per month. At the end of year 3, you will have to do an overhaul and that costs \$30,000. Assume that MARR is 1.5% per month and ignore the effect of taxes and depreciation.

**Solution:**

[image]

Comment: You are getting the italics because dollar signs are used to enclose $\LaTeX$ on this site.  To write a money amount with a dollar sign, you need dollar backslash dollar 500 dollar to get $\$500$.  You should be able to edit those in.  For more information see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The initial payment of $\$100,000 $ is to be deducted immediately from the $\$240, 000 $, so the respective cash flows  are represented by lines with arrows in opposite directions. As for the calculated monthly payments in my opinion they should have the same direction of the initial payment.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect the 100,000 would be shown like this since I can't picture it as savings or revenue. It does make sense though since the diagram has to show part of the 240,000 has been paid for.